# How to Optimize below cypher query for implementing pagination

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (user:Users {id: 1})<-[ct:COMMENT]<-(co:Comment)<-[ct_by:COMMENTED_BY]-(c_user:Users)
OPTIONAL MATCH (co)<-[rt:REPLY]<-(r_co:Comment)<-[r_co_by:REPLIED_BY]-(r_co_user:Users)
OPTIONAL MATCH (co)<-[co_lk:LIKES]-(co_lk_user:Users)
OPTIONAL MATCH (r_co)<-[r_co_lk:LIKES]-(r_co_lk_user:Users)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)<-[rv:REVIEW]-(rv_user:Users)
RETURN co,c_user,r_co,r_co_user,rv,rv_user,COUNT(co_lk_user) AS co_likes,COUNT(r_co_lk) AS r_co_likes ORDER BY ct_by.created_at DESC, r_co_by.created_at
```

Above cypher is written for fetching all comments, reply and likes on that comments along with review against an user similar to user feed. Output of above query is mess and handled at application layer along with pagination. 
Any suggestions on how to optimize above cypher along with pagination in query itself would be really helpfull.

Comment: Also, is there any way for you to alter the graph so your `created_at` properties are on the :Comment nodes instead of the relationships? That would allow ordering and pagination without having to expand to the user nodes that are replying or commenting.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem with this query is that you're not using aggregation to collect independent segments of data, so you're getting cross products between them instead, which is leading to duplication of results in your data and very likely throwing off your counts as well.

For example, in your return, you are generating cross products between your comments and your reviews. In fact, I'd really recommend getting reviews in a separate query, otherwise (provided you collect your reviews) you'll be getting the same reviews with every single record, and that seems wasteful.

Here's an alternate query that should work better for you (for now, keeping collected reviews in the query):

```
MATCH (user:Users {id: 1})
WITH user, [(user)<-[rv:REVIEW]-(rv_user:Users) | rv {.*, reviewer:rv_user}] as reviews
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)<-[:COMMENT]-(co:Comment)<-[ct_by:COMMENTED_BY]-(c_user:Users)
WITH reviews, co, ct_by, c_user
OPTIONAL MATCH (co)<-[:REPLY]-(r_co:Comment)<-[r_co_by:REPLIED_BY]-(r_co_user:Users)
WITH reviews, co, ct_by, c_user, r_co, r_co_by, r_co_user
ORDER BY ct_by.created_at DESC, r_co_by.created_at 
SKIP $skip LIMIT $limit
RETURN reviews, co, ct_by, c_user, r_co, r_co_user, size((co)<-[:LIKES]-()) AS co_likes, size((r_co)<-[:LIKES]-()) AS r_co_likes
```

We're using a combination of pattern comprehension and map projection in the first WITH clause to collect reviews along with the reviewer.

After we finish matching out to `ct_by` and `r_co_by` we can apply pagination with SKIP and LIMIT, though you'll need to supply those parameters, and call the query for the next page, skipping in multiples of the limit (you can alter these accordingly if that makes it easier).

We're using the `size()` function on a pattern to get the number of occurrences, this is easier for getting the likes, especially as it's getting this from the relationship degree data on the node itself rather than having to expand (provided that all :LIKES relationships are from :Users).

We can improve even more from here, for example, collecting the reply data for each comment:

```
MATCH (user:Users {id: 1})
WITH user, [(user)<-[rv:REVIEW]-(rv_user:Users) | rv {.*, reviewer:rv_user}] as reviews
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)<-[:COMMENT]-(co:Comment)<-[ct_by:COMMENTED_BY]-(c_user:Users)
WITH reviews, co, ct_by, c_user
OPTIONAL MATCH (co)<-[:REPLY]-(r_co:Comment)<-[r_co_by:REPLIED_BY]-(r_co_user:Users)
WITH reviews, co, ct_by, c_user, r_co, r_co_by, r_co_user
ORDER BY ct_by.created_at DESC, r_co_by.created_at 
SKIP $skip LIMIT $limit
WITH reviews, co, ct_by, c_user, r_co, r_co_user, size((co)<-[:LIKES]-()) AS co_likes, size((r_co)<-[:LIKES]-()) AS r_co_likes
RETURN reviews, co, ct_by, c_user, co_likes, collect(r_co {.*, replier:r_co_user, likes:r_co_likes}) as replies
```